# make divs which are stacked vertically inside a container all the same width

Tags: html, css

I have a container div which has four vertically stacked divs. Each of these divs contains text and changes on page load. I'm trying to style the four stacked divs so I can change their background according to whether they are odd rows or even rows.

I can do this alright but I need the stacked divs to be the all as wide as the container.

```
<ul class="level2">
<li><div class="subCatodd"><a href="cPath=8">Clothes</a></div></li>
<li><div class="subCateven"><a href="cPath=9">Hats</a></div></li>
<li><div class="subCatodd"><a href="cPath=10">kitchen</a></div></li>
</ul>
```

I can't get the subCatodd/subCateven divs to fill the width of the ul

can anyone help me out?

EDIT:
heres the css I have (should have posted it already sorry)

```
div#dropMenu ul.level2 {-moz-border-radius: 5px;-webkit-border-radius: 5px;border-radius: 5px;background-image:url(../images/dropdownbg.gif); background-repeat:repeat-x;padding:8px 0px; background-color:#7b631d;font-size:13px;white-space: nowrap;}
div#dropMenu ul.level2 a {color: white;}  /* this is text color on drop-down submenu */
div#dropMenu ul.level2 a:hover {color:#e0e211;}
.subCatodd{background-color:#7b631d;padding:10px 25px 10px 25px;}
.subCateven {background-color:#665011;padding:10px 25px 10px 25px;}
div#dropMenu ul.level2 {top: 50px;z-index:1000;}
```

**2nd EDIT:**
here's a fiddle with my exact code, if anyone can make this work I'd be very grateful
http://jsfiddle.net/3fazn/2/

Comment: Does the container ul have a width?

Comment: Nope, because it's meant to expand to fit the different text which might appear in the verticle divs. Is that the problem?

Comment: please check out the new fiddle in the 2nd EDIT in my original Qu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about just floating your ul container so it wraps the width of the contained content:

```
ul { float:left; }
.subCatodd { background:#bdb; }
.subCateven { background:#dbd; }
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xzHAU/1/) to demonstrate (**EDIT**: I've updated the fiddle to use your css).

Alternatively you could set display to inline block on the containing ul, just know that it won't work in IE7 as ul isn't inline by default. Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xzHAU/2/) for that version.

**EDIT**: Here's the latest version - I added the child selector I mentioned below in the comments and removed the width values from the classes you're using to zebra-stripe - is this what you're trying to achieve: http://jsfiddle.net/3fazn/7/

Comment: Hey there, thanks. I tried floating my ul like you suggest but that didn't help. This is all part of a css dropdown nav thing so I've stuck the whole thing in this fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/3fazn/

Comment: There's still some issues with the fiddle. The markup is invalid and I've re-formatted the css for readability (http://jsfiddle.net/3fazn/6/) I've corrected the markup, but it's difficult to tell what you're trying to accomplish from this so far. One thing I *think* you're trying to do is to have the dropdown ul's stack the li's vertically. If so, you'll need to at the very least, change the selector that floats the li's left to only be the immediate children of the ul - so use div#dropMenu>li instead of div#dropMenu li so it doesn't apply to the nested li's.

Comment: thanks for helping me out with this. Yes having the div vertically stacked is one of the things, I only realised that wasn't happening on chrome and safari because it works fine on FF. The thing I'm trying to do is have the darker and lighter bands be the full width of the containing div and for those containing divs to be the size (plus a bit of padding) of the widest bit of text in the verticle column. I hope that makes sense!

Comment: I do believe it is! Happy daze! Thanks so much for taking the time to help me out :)

Answer (score 2):

It will be better if you create a child `css` selector for the odd `divs` (as shown in the jsFiddle mentioned below).

Check out this jsFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/SsM4V/12/

Is this what you are looking for?

**Edit:** Modified the jsFiddle after the comment

Comment: This is kinda right in that it's more correct but unfortunately the same problem. I'm having trouble getting a fiddle to work like on my localhost unfortunately, I think because I don't have a width set for the ul container so on fiddle it fills the screen, but I can't set a width because the container is just meant to expand according to what text is in it.

Comment: I think you could add `display:inline-block;` to the wrapper element to get it to re-size according to the content. Check this jsFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/SsM4V/12/